# C++ character count (Project Euler 17 wrong answer)

Tags: c++, string

I am getting a wrong answer when I wrote a code to solve [Prob 17 in Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=17).
I am outputting every string to make the count more clear.

The link is posted here: http://codepad.org/wE54t7Qi

Can someone help me to determine where the problem is?

```
map<long int, string> CharNumberValue;

int main()
{

CharNumberValue[0] ="zero";
CharNumberValue[1] ="one";
CharNumberValue[2] ="two";
CharNumberValue[3] ="three";
CharNumberValue[4] ="four";
CharNumberValue[5] ="five";
CharNumberValue[6] ="six";
CharNumberValue[7] ="seven";
CharNumberValue[8] ="eight";
CharNumberValue[9] ="nine";
CharNumberValue[10] ="ten";
CharNumberValue[11] ="eleven";
CharNumberValue[12] ="twelve";
CharNumberValue[13] ="thirteen";
CharNumberValue[14] ="fourteen";
CharNumberValue[15] ="fifteen";
CharNumberValue[16] ="sixteen";
CharNumberValue[17] ="seventeen";
CharNumberValue[18] ="eighteen";
CharNumberValue[19] ="nineteen";
CharNumberValue[20] ="twenty";
CharNumberValue[30] ="thirty";
CharNumberValue[40] ="forty";
CharNumberValue[50] ="fifty";
CharNumberValue[60] ="sixty";
CharNumberValue[70] ="seventy";
CharNumberValue[80] ="eighty";
CharNumberValue[90] ="ninety";
CharNumberValue[100] ="hundred";//Sameer,remember 100 is one hundred
CharNumberValue[1000] ="thousand";//Sameer,remember 1000 is one thousand

  long int count = 0; 
  string printword ="";

for(int i=1; i< 1000; i++)
{

    if(i<=100)
    {
        int ten = (i/10)*10;
        int unit = i%10;    
        map<long int, string>:: iterator it = CharNumberValue.find(i);
        map<long int, string>:: iterator it1 = CharNumberValue.find(unit);
        map<long int, string>:: iterator it2 = CharNumberValue.find(ten);

        if(i<10)
        {
            count  += it1->second.length();
            printword = it1->second;
            cout<<printword<<endl;
        }
        if(i>=10 && i<=20)
        {
            count  += it->second.length();//These are unique
            printword = it->second;
            cout<<printword<<endl;
        }
        if(i>20 && i<=100) 
        {

            count  += it2->second.length();
            printword = it2->second ;
            if ((i != 30)&&(i != 40)&&(i != 50)&&(i != 60)&&(i != 70)&&(i != 80)&&(i!= 90)&&(i!= 100))
            {
                count  += it1->second.length();
                printword = it2->second + " " + it1->second ;

            }
            cout<<printword<<endl;              
        }           

    }
    if(i>100 && i<1000)
    {
        int hun = i/100;
        int ten=i%100;
        int mten = (ten/10)*10;//modified ten
        int unit = ten%10;

        map<long int, string>:: iterator it = CharNumberValue.find(unit);
        map<long int, string>:: iterator it1 = CharNumberValue.find(mten);          
        map<long int, string>:: iterator it2 = CharNumberValue.find(ten);
        map<long int, string>:: iterator it3 = CharNumberValue.find(hun);           
        int counttemp = CharNumberValue[100].length();
        count  += it3->second.length() + CharNumberValue[100].length();
        printword = it3->second + " " + CharNumberValue[100];

        if((i != 200)&&(i != 300)&&(i != 400)&&(i != 500)&&(i != 600)&&(i != 700)&&(i != 800)&&(i != 900))
        {
            if( ten<=20)
            {
                count  += 3/*for and */+ it2->second.length()   ;//These are unique
                printword = it3->second + " " + CharNumberValue[100]  + " and "  + it2->second ;
                cout<<printword<<endl;
            }

            if(ten>20 && ten<=99) 
            {
                count  += 3/*for and */+ it1->second.length();
                printword = it3->second + " " + CharNumberValue[100]  + " and "  + it1->second;
                if ((ten != 30)&&(ten != 40)&&(ten != 50)&&(ten != 60)&&(ten != 70)&&(ten != 80)&&(ten!= 90)&&(ten!= 100))
                {
                    count  += it->second.length();
                    printword = it3->second + " " + CharNumberValue[100]  + " and "  + it1->second +" "+ it->second ;
                }

                cout<<printword<<endl;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            cout<<printword<<endl;
        }
    }
}
count += 11;//for one thousand
cout<< count;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [include code in the question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#make-sure-you-include-your-code-in-your-question).

Comment: It probably would be beneficial if you put the count of *each* entry next to its output that way you can verify total is correct.

Comment: I have no time for a complete code-review but I do know the answer of that problem. Do you want the answer to any of these questions : what is the answer ? Am I far from the right answer ? Is my answer too big or too small ?

Comment: @Josay: I want my code to generate the right answer.

Comment: Ok, I can understand this, it's all credit to you. I asked just in case you wanted to know how big the gap was to be able to find the problem in your code.

Comment: palacsint:Just did
Casey: The display adds to the string based on the condition. Are you suggesting that I should add and subtract from the printed string?
Josay: Thank you. I think maybe I am not counting the a particular number properly OR I am counting something extra and counting something else incorrectly.

Comment: Code Review is strictly for working code. Since you are trying to correct a flaw in your code it is off topic for that site.

Comment: @WinstonEwert:I am asking to review my code which is not working correctly. Its not that there is a flaw in the code, there is a logical glitch which gives me the wrong answer. Can you explain why is this not a question meant to be asked here? What rules am I breaking by asking this question?

Comment: @SameerShah, a logical glitch *is* a flaw your the code. Code Review is strictly for working code. We improve code in other ways such as style/performance not correctness.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: The same question was initially put on stackoverflow site. It was closed down suggesting that it should have been asked on code review.
And if you see the 'Related' section (on your right) there are similar questions being asked ->asking for the correctness of the program.
There seems to be a lot of difference between your view and other admins/moderators.<br/>
If you say that this is a wrong place to ask this question, please suggest the right place to ask this question.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Please check the comments on this closed question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808732/incorrect-string-count-project-euler-17-using-c

Comment: @SameerShah, the related questions on your right are now from stackoverflow not code review, because I moved your question to stackoverflow. As you see, there are many questions here giving help on the correctness of code. If you find similiar questions on CodeReview you'll see they have almost all been migrated to stackoverflow.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Sir, I am not saying that what you did or did not do is wrong. I am just saying that there is a lot of difference of opinion among administrators and moderators. Some people think that this question should be put on code review, some think, it should be on stack overflow.

Comment: @SameerShah Since you have a problem in your code, [SO] is the right place for the question. However, questions that just provide a large amount of code and ask the community members to debug it don't tend to do very well here. SO is not a debugging service. In addition to that, your question is very specific to your situation and is unlikely to help future visitors (since they won't be making the program the same way and would be unlikely to make the same output formatting mistake you did. This is why your first version of this question (and shortly this one) are closed as "too localized".

Comment: @SameerShah Code Review is *only* for code that isn't broken in any way.

Comment: @SameerShah, sorry about all the bouncing and confusion. What Mod suggested that your question belonged on Code Review? As far as I can tell, only another user incorrectly suggested that. If there is a mod who thinks this belongs on code review please identify so we can get that straightened out.

Comment: @AnnaLear: My code isn't broken in anyway.So based on the reason why this problem is closed, shouldn't this be closed too?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792721/problem-with-project-euler-problem-18

Comment: @SameerShah Your code wasn't producing an expected output, right? That counts as broken. I agree about the other question and have closed it as Too Localized as well.

Comment: @WinstonEwert: I am sorry, I thought that user was a mod. But then again, where should I ask such questions?

Comment: @SameerShah This might be a good time for a meta post... would you mind asking on [meta] about questions like these? Then the community can help decide if they belong on Stack Overflow in general or not.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I sure will. Once again, I have deepest of respect and admiration for people who are willing to discuss codes. I am not a person who dumps the code on someone so that they can solve it and give me an answer, and I can take credit for it. Rather, I look at it as a process of DISCUSSION

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're outputting "hundred" instead of "one hundred".

Comment: I know but I did add count +=11 for that. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. But why didn't you just loop until <= 1000 ?

Comment: I am actually developing a function to count words for larger numbers too. But for answer purposes I just added 11. Do you think I am making mistake there?

Comment: No, it's fine. I edited my post with the solution... that was annoying to track down.

Comment: This should lead to the right answer. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

- You can simplify most of the tests containing enumeration of cases :

  ```
  if ((i != 30)&&(i != 40)&&(i != 50)&&(i != 60)&&(i != 70)&&(i != 80)&&(i!= 90)&&(i!= 100))
  ```

  As (i>20 && i<=100), you can just check if i is a multiple of 10 (using variable unit for instance)

  ```
  if((i != 200)&&(i != 300)&&(i != 400)&&(i != 500)&&(i != 600)&&(i != 700)&&(i != 800)&&(i != 900))
  ```

  As (i>100 && i<1000), you can just check if i is a multiple of 100

  ```
  if ((ten != 30)&&(ten != 40)&&(ten != 50)&&(ten != 60)&&(ten != 70)&&(ten != 80)&&(ten!= 90)&&(ten!= 100))
  ```

  As (ten>20 && ten<=99), you can just check if ten is a multiple of 10.
- More generally, the shorter your code is, the easier it will be to find a mistake. This includes removing useless tests (a few of the conditions above were useless because of the bounds of the variables), removing duplicate code, etc.

Comment: I agree.Thanks Josay. Let me try this.